# nodejs elastic client getMapping don't give mapp

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I don't have Success to get the map of the index by

```
client.indices.getMapping([params, [callback]])
```

the function does reach the call back. I do it this way:

```
client.indices.getMapping({index: 'patents'}, function(error, response) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try for this:

```
client.indices.getMapping({
index: "indexname",
type:"type"
}, function (error, response) {
if(error){   
logger.error(error);
})
```

Comment: thank you !! but its not give me the full mapping its give me somthing like {_shards:{total:10, secss:10, faild : 0}}

Comment: @david lopez I think you are looking for shards details. Gte mapping should be different.

Comment: {"index":{"mappings":{"type":{"properties":{"geolocation":{"type":"string"},"id_0":{"type":"string"}}}}